Does the anticommutator of two spinors affect the transpose of their product?
My lecture notes claim that for an anticommutation relation
$$[ \psi_{\mu}(\bf{x},t),{\psi_{{\nu}}^{*}}(\bf{y},t)] = \delta_{\mu \nu} \delta^3(\bf{x}-\bf{y})$$
between two spinors, the transpose of the expression $$a^{\mu}=\psi^* \gamma^{\mu} \psi$$ picks up a minus sign and becomes $$({a^{\mu}})^T \stackrel{?}{=} -\psi^T (\gamma^{\mu})^T \bar{\psi}.$$
I am confused about this and about the general relation between the commutator and the transpose of the product of two spinors. In a general example, if $A$ and $B$ anticommute $$[ A,B] = 0$$ then $$(AB)^T = (-BA)^T = -A^T  B^T$$ but I don't see how this affects the truth value of the expression $$(AB)^T = B^T A^T.$$ Is the last expression no longer true if $A$ and $B$ do not commute?

The trick is that matrices are composed of complex numbers, which are commutative numbers. Spinors are composed of Grass Mann numbers, which are anticommutative. If you write down the calculations in components, the sign should pop out

Using index notation clears this up instantly. By definition the transpose of a matrix satisfies
$$
(A^T)_{ij} =  A_{ji} .
$$
The transpose of a product of matrices is,
$$
[(AB)^T]_{ij} = (AB)_{ji} = A_{jk} B_{ki}
$$
At this stage, we need to exchange $A_{jk} \leftrightarrow B_{ki}$ to bring it into matrix form. This picks up an extra sign if both $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ are Grassmann-valued. It follows
$$
[(AB)^T]_{ij} = \pm B_{ki} A_{jk} = \pm (B^T)_{ik} (A^T)_{kj} = ( \pm B^T A^T)_{ij}
$$
Going back to matrix notation,
$$
(AB)^T = \pm B^T A^T.
$$
where we use $+$ sign if either $A$ or $B$ is complex-valued and we use the $-$ sign if both $A$ and $B$ are Grassmann-valued.
